# catch a exception with specific message

Tags: java, exception

Is there a better way for catching specific Exception with a message then doing this:

```
try{
   methodThatWillProbablyThrowASocketException();
} catch(SocketException e){
   if(e.getMessage().contains("reset")){
      // the connection was reset
      // will ignore
   } else{
      throw e;
   }
}
```

For example the `HttpStatusException` gives me the Method `getStatusCode()` where i can easily compare if the error status was 404 or 502 and the can decide what to do:

```
try{
   methodThatWillProbablyThrowAHTTPException();
} catch(HttpStatusException e){
   if(e.getStatusCode() == 404){
      // not found, will not continue
   } 
   if else(e.getStatusCode() == 502){
      // server errror, try again
   } else{
      throw e;
   }
}
```

Most other Exceptions dont give me prober Methods, just the Message.

So my question is, is it the right way to do it? With String compares? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do one thing .

1. Collect all types of exception that are likely to be occur for your project.
2. Make a separate class by extending Exception.
3. Override the getCause() method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause%28%29

**public Throwable getCause()**

Define codes you want for different exceptions Like null-pointer 101 ,,   so on......

The use that class every where . So you have to write exception only once and you can use with as many projects.

After building the class it will be reusable for all your needs

If you getting new conditions, update this class only and all the things will be done

This is a better solution according to me...

This way you can get functionality for which you are looking. you have to make it by yourself.

Comment: okay, but still then i need to do the .getMessage() thing to check for the exception and substitute it with my code

Comment: @reox Ya that is completely true but something we to do for full filling our own purposes

Answer (score 3):

Relying on code or status code is fine but relying on message could be problematic as the message can change.

You should look to refactor and define multiple exceptions or define codes for different scenarios.

Comment: the problem is, i'm not only using my own exceptions but also libs or java core stuff like `java.net.SocketException` - so refactoring could be lead to real trouble...

Comment: In that exception what are the multiple scenarios for which you receive different message and what you want to do different in those scenarios?

Comment: the question is just if there is a better way to check for an exception with a specific message then doing a string compare on the message itself. Or is there any other method in Exception or Throwable that i can call to get the details of an exception.

Comment: there is nothing else in SocketException which you can rely on. May be check what comes in the getCause() otherwise your best bet in this case is getMessage() only.